# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, memory-limit

While fetching more than 300k records in mysql, i'm getting error like this

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>
> Project\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_result.php on line 229.

I have increased memory_limit up to 1024M and changed to -1 also.

i can't find the solution till

Comment: I think it's more useful to spend your time working out how to more efficiently process the data.  Do you really need to load all of the records at the same time?

Comment: Yes i want to load all the data in quick speed

Comment: What for?  Understanding why you need this data and how you use it may help in fixing your problem, at the moment there isn't much anyone can do.

Comment: Why can't you limit fetched items count and get it in smaller chunks? But you have to do something with data and destroy it from memory. Otherwise you will hit same error.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: What possible use could there be in having 300,000 row of (unknown size) in memory at one time. What on earth are you going to do with all that data, surely not show it on a web page

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP Generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) instead

```
function getData()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    $q= $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        yield $row;
    }
}

foreach ($this->getData() as $record) {
    //
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this over putting all of the code where the `yield $row;` is?

Comment: A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate. Instead, you can write a generator function, which is the same as a normal function, except that instead of returning once, a generator can yield as many times as it needs to in order to provide the values to be iterated over.

Comment: do some research about PHP Generators (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)

Comment: My point is that instead of processing the data in the`foreach()`, you could include the same code in the `while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {` loop. So instead of making this shorter you are adding an extra loop to the process.

Comment: I am afraid, I don't know much about Codeigniter. I am sure codeigniter provide raw query execution as well?